# How can I syncronization time with TCP Server

Tags: c, mfc, tcpclient

I'm make TCP Client with some protocol documents

I have problem with Time syncronization with the server

When the server send me a OPCODE and RTC time, Client have to syncronization time.

I try use SYSTEMTIME and SetSystemTime, but SetSystemTime need a Administrator permission

How can I synchronization time with server???

```
void CSystemManagementDlg::SynchronizationTime(char* buffer)
{
    //buffer[50]
    char ChangeTime[15];
    memcpy(ChangeTime,&buffer[52],12);

    SYSTEMTIME ChngTime;
    int year, month, day, hour, minute, second;
    
    sscanf(ChangeTime, "2%3d%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d", year, month, day, hour, minute, &second);

    ChngTime.wYear = (WORD)year;
    ChngTime.wMonth = (WORD)month;
    ChngTime.wDay = (WORD)day;
    ChngTime.wHour = (WORD)hour;
    ChngTime.wMinute = (WORD)minute;
    ChngTime.wSecond = (WORD)second;

    if (SetSystemTime(&ChngTime) == 0) {
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Use Network Time Protocol?

Comment: @Lieu,  `SYSTEMTIME` has 8 members.  What value to the 2 uninitialized members have when `SetSystemTime(&ChngTime)` is called?

Comment: @dimich No, the server just sends me time to synchronize the time.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, I'm sorry. I didn't understand. The code I tried was already showing a strange value from here. `ChngTime.wYear = (WORD)year;`

Comment: As explained in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-setsystemtime): *"The calling process must have the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege."* If the client process doesn't hold this privilege then it cannot change the system time. Other than setting this privilege, there is no other way to allow a process to change the system time.

Comment: @IInspectable,  Is there any way to change the localtime for the received time?

Comment: Local time is derived from system time. To change local time, you'll have to change the system time. Since the system time contributes to, for example, verification of digital certificates it is a protected resource. Only processes that hold the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege are allowed to change it. All that said, it much sounds like you're attempting to apply a global solution to a local problem. You'll probably have to invest some more time into understanding the *problem*.

Comment: @IInspectable I have to try using `SetSystemTime(&ChngTime)`

Comment: Of course you can *try*. But unless the calling process holds the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege, all it does is return `0` and have no side effect (beyond setting the calling thread's last error code).

Comment: @IInspectable I have to find the process holds the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel like this isn't adding much...

The question already states that calling [`SetSystemTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-setsystemtime) requires administrator permission. While this isn't entirely accurate (the calling process must hold the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege), it still acknowledges that you cannot change the system time willy-nilly.

And that's that, there's no way around it.

---

The options here are:

- Acquire the `SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME` privilege from within the process (which requires the `TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES` privilege, so you're back to square one)
- Have someone else (such as an installer application) grant the privilege (which, again, requires "administrator" privileges along the way)
- Update the local security policy to include whichever account is going to run the application (which, again, requires "administrator" privileges, so no forward progress here either)
- Don't apply a [global solution to a local problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081211-00/?p=19873)

With all remaining alternatives requiring privileges that the calling code (apparently) don't hold, the final option is the one that's worth pursuing:

As I read the problem statement, the issue that needs to be addressed is in correlating timestamps between a client and a server, that do not agree on what `now()` is.

While a server generally services multiple clients it would seem obvious to treat the server's understanding of the current time as the *"single source of truth"*. In this hypothetical (yet practical) setup, clients would want to *record* their deviation from the (server's) state, and use that data when communication with the outside world.

The *"outside world"* here is both the server, as well as the client's UI. When accepting messages from the server, or sending messages to the server, the client would need to account for the offset in time. Likewise, the client's UI displaying server times needs to acknowledge the time skew.

---

The bottom line being: A client needs to acknowledge that its state is (potentially) different from the server's. It needs to record its discrepancy, and apply offsets as required. Subtraction is a solved problem (so long as floating point values aren't involved, or C meeting signed arithmetic).